# How Do I get the following linkedtextview code to work in my layout file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, textview

I am using a layout (news_headline.xml) such that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.jar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/news_headline_padding" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_headline_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_first_headline_text" 
        foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_header_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/news_headline_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/metadata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_item_subtitle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/metadata" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/news_headline_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/news_headline_image"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_headline_text" 
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_headline_image"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:contentDescription="@string/headline_image" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I am planning to add the following block of code within the layout say below the textviews(and i did try that and was able to run without error):

```
<com.justin.jar.views.LinkableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_body"
                    foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/news_body"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/article_body"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It is realted to the following java file LinkableTextView.java:

```
public class LinkableTextView extends FontTextView {

    private final ArrayList<Hyperlink> mListOfLinks;
    private SpannableString mLinkableText;
    TextLinkClickListener mListener;
    private static final String ARTICLE_REPLACE_STRING = "(Full Story)";

    private static final String ARTICLE_PATTERN = "\\[ID:nL\\w+\\]";
    private static final String SYMBOL_PATTERN = "<\\S+?>";
    private static final String LINK_PATTERN = "(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

    public LinkableTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mListOfLinks = new ArrayList<Hyperlink>();
    }

    public LinkableTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final String pattern) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mListOfLinks = new ArrayList<Hyperlink>();
    }

    public SpannableString gatherArticleLinks(final String text) {
        mListOfLinks.clear();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            return null;
        }

        mLinkableText = new SpannableString(text);
        gatherLinks(mListOfLinks, mLinkableText, ARTICLE_PATTERN);

        for (int i = 0; i < mListOfLinks.size(); i++) {
            final Hyperlink linkSpec = mListOfLinks.get(i);
            mLinkableText.setSpan(linkSpec.span, linkSpec.start, linkSpec.end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

        setText(mLinkableText);
        return mLinkableText;
    }

    public void setOnTextLinkClickListener(final TextLinkClickListener newListener) {
        mListener = newListener;
    }

    /**
     * this method parses the article from start to end looking for three different patterns (Articles, Symbols and Links)
     * it will process the first matched pattern first and continue parsing from the end of the last found pattern.
     * The process will end when none of the patterns match any more
     * @param links
     * @param spannable
     * @param patternString
     */
    private final void gatherLinks(final ArrayList<Hyperlink> links, final Spannable spannable, final String patternString) {
        Pattern patternArticle = Pattern.compile(ARTICLE_PATTERN);
        Pattern patternSymbol = Pattern.compile(SYMBOL_PATTERN);
        Pattern patternLink = Pattern.compile(LINK_PATTERN);

        boolean isArticleFinished = false;
        boolean isSymbolFinished = false;
        boolean isLinkFinished = false;

        final Matcher matcherArticle = patternArticle.matcher(spannable);
        final Matcher matcherSymbol = patternSymbol.matcher(spannable);
        final Matcher matcherLink = patternLink.matcher(spannable);

        final StringBuilder articleBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int lastParsedIndex = 0;

        while (!isArticleFinished || !isSymbolFinished || !isLinkFinished) {

            int startArticle = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if (!isArticleFinished) {
                if (matcherArticle.find(lastParsedIndex)) {
                    startArticle = matcherArticle.start();
                } else {
                    isArticleFinished = true;
                }
            }

            int startSymbol = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if (!isSymbolFinished) {
                if (matcherSymbol.find(lastParsedIndex)) {
                    startSymbol = matcherSymbol.start();
                } else {
                    isSymbolFinished = true;
                }
            }

            int startLink = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if (!isLinkFinished) {
                if (matcherLink.find(lastParsedIndex)) {
                    startLink = matcherLink.start();
                } else {
                    isLinkFinished = true;
                }
            }

            Hyperlink spec = new Hyperlink();
            String matchedText;
            if (startArticle < startSymbol && startArticle < startLink) { //Article link is first and it will be processed
                if (!isArticleFinished) {
                    int endArticle = matcherArticle.end();
                    if (startArticle == lastParsedIndex) {
                        articleBuilder.append(" ");
                    }
                    articleBuilder.append(spannable.subSequence(lastParsedIndex, startArticle));
                    matchedText = spannable.subSequence(startArticle, endArticle).toString();
                    spec.span = new InternalArticleURLSpan(matchedText);
                    spec.start = articleBuilder.length();
                    articleBuilder.append(ARTICLE_REPLACE_STRING);
                    spec.end = articleBuilder.length();

                    links.add(spec);
                    lastParsedIndex = endArticle;
                }
            } else if (startSymbol < startArticle && startSymbol < startLink) { //Symbol Link is first and it will be processed
                if (!isSymbolFinished) {
                    int endSymbol = matcherSymbol.end();
                    if (startSymbol == lastParsedIndex) {
                        articleBuilder.append(" ");
                    }
                    articleBuilder.append(spannable.subSequence(lastParsedIndex, startSymbol));
                    matchedText = spannable.subSequence(startSymbol, endSymbol).toString();
                    spec.span = new InternalSymbolURLSpan(matchedText);
                    spec.start = articleBuilder.length();
                    articleBuilder.append(spec.span.getLinkText(matchedText));
                    spec.end = articleBuilder.length();
                    links.add(spec);
                    lastParsedIndex = endSymbol;
                }
            } else {
                if (!isLinkFinished) { //Http Link is first so it will be processed
                    int endLink = matcherLink.end();
                    if (startLink == lastParsedIndex) {
                        articleBuilder.append(" ");
                    }
                    articleBuilder.append(spannable.subSequence(lastParsedIndex, startLink));
                    matchedText = spannable.subSequence(startLink, endLink).toString();
                    spec.span = new InternalLinkURLSpan(matchedText);
                    spec.start = articleBuilder.length();
                    articleBuilder.append(spec.span.getLinkText(matchedText));
                    spec.end = articleBuilder.length();
                    links.add(spec);
                    lastParsedIndex = endLink;
                }
            }
        }

        articleBuilder.append(spannable.subSequence(lastParsedIndex, spannable.length()));

        mLinkableText = new SpannableString(articleBuilder.toString());
    }

    public abstract class InternalURLSpan extends ClickableSpan {
        public abstract String getLinkText(final String clickedSpan);
    }

    public class InternalArticleURLSpan extends InternalURLSpan {
        private final String clickedSpan;
        private Pattern mPattern;

        public InternalArticleURLSpan(final String clickedString) {
            setPattern();
            clickedSpan = getLinkText(clickedString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View textView) {
            mListener.onArticleClick(textView, clickedSpan);
        }

        public String getLinkText(final String clickedSpan) {
            if (mPattern != null) {
                final Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(clickedSpan);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    return matcher.group();
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid article ID:" + clickedSpan);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void setPattern() {
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?=\\])");
        }

    }

    public class InternalSymbolURLSpan extends InternalURLSpan {
        private final String clickedSpan;

        public InternalSymbolURLSpan(final String clickedString) {
            clickedSpan = getLinkText(clickedString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View textView) {
            mListener.onSymbolClick(textView, clickedSpan);
        }

        public String getLinkText(final String clickedSpan) {
            return clickedSpan.substring(1, clickedSpan.length()-1);
        }
    }

    public class InternalLinkURLSpan extends InternalURLSpan {
        private final String clickedSpan;

        public InternalLinkURLSpan(final String clickedString) {
            clickedSpan = getLinkText(clickedString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View textView) {
            mListener.onLinkClick(textView, clickedSpan);
        }

        public String getLinkText(final String clickedSpan) {
            return clickedSpan;
        }
    }

    class Hyperlink {
        InternalURLSpan span;
        int start;
        int end;
    }

}
```

But everytime I add that block of code within the xml code and run, it shows nothing, as in a blank , as if the code was never used(rest of the code appears just fine).How do I make it visible (Note: it works fine in another xml file which is a linearlayout and is using the entire page for the info display).

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention it's position in `RelativeLayout` and I am unable to find in your code, so if this is the problem, then check with it or you can come back with more specific issue so that there might be chances of having my answer edited according to that.

In `LinearLayout` it worked because it either places elements in `vertical or horizontal orientation`. But in the `RelativeLayout` if you don't mention it's positions, one view replaces the other. This might be the problem.

Comment: how do I mention it's position in the relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify where you want it to be. Say you want it below `metadat` `TextView`. Give it the `android:layout_below` property. Something like this

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/metadata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_item_subtitle"
    android:textSize="@dimen/metadata" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/news_headline_text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/news_headline_image"
    android:layout_below="@id/news_headline_text" 
    />
<com.justin.jar.views.LinkableTextView
    android:id="@+id/news_body"
    foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
    android:textSize="@dimen/news_body"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/article_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/metadata" />    //this line here
```

By default, `View`s in a `RelativeLayout` are positioned in the top-left so if something else is there then it may be covering this `View` without giving it a position within the `layout`. If this doesn't solve your problem then please post how your tried to put it in there and maybe a picture of what you want and/or are getting.